# Can't access one item in array but I can access whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the first function I'm performing a get request with fetch and storing the id numbers of multiple objects from the database into the variable groupIds. I return groupIds from this first function. In a second function I can console.log the entire array of groupIds successfully, but I get undefined when I console.log(groupIds[0]). Why? How to I console.log one index of the array correctly?

```
function fetchAllIdsInGroup(){
    let groupIds = [];
    let groupNumber = document.querySelector('#groupNumber').value;

    fetch('http://localhost:1234/allIdsInGroup/' + groupNumber)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            groupIds.push(element['_id'])
        });
        return groupIds;
    })
    return groupIds;
}
```

```
function printAllIdsInGroup(){

    let testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    console.log(testArray[0]); // this works
    // outputs
    // a

    let groupIds = fetchAllIdsInGroup();

    console.log(fetchAllIdsInGroup()); // This works
    // outputs
    // 0: "5ed5959428d39b33acc26f16"
    // 1: "5edd8219f95cf602d4741a1a"
    // 2: "5edd8233f95cf602d4741a1b"

    console.log(groupIds); // This works
    // outputs
    // 0: "5ed5959428d39b33acc26f16"
    // 1: "5edd8219f95cf602d4741a1a"
    // 2: "5edd8233f95cf602d4741a1b"

    console.log(groupIds[0]); // Doesn't work
    // outputs 
    // undefined
}
```

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: what gives `console.log(typeof groupIds)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your group ids are being fetch asynchronously, you need to wait for a response before accessing the variable. You can use async await for it

```
async function fetchAllIdsInGroup(){
    let groupIds = [];
    let groupNumber = document.querySelector('#groupNumber').value;

    await fetch('http://localhost:1234/allIdsInGroup/' + groupNumber)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data.forEach(element => {
            groupIds.push(element['_id'])
        });
    });
    return groupIds;
}

async function printAllIdsInGroup(){

    let testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    console.log(testArray[0]); // this works
    // outputs
    // a

    let groupIds = await fetchAllIdsInGroup();

    console.log(groupIds[0]);
}
```

PS. The reason you were able to see the whole array in console is because the console values are also resolved lazily and so by the time you expand the array, the data would be avaiable